# How can I mix and match VS Code themes

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to mix and match themes in VS Code?

I want to keep the background colours of the default "Dark+" theme, but at the same time I want to set the font colors to "One Dark Pro"'s font colors.

I have tried modifying the settings.json file with the following config:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "strings": "#98C379",
    "functions": "#5AA1DC",
    "keywords": "#C477DB",
    "numbers": "#D19A66",
    "types": "#E5C07B",
    "variables": "#E06C75",
    "comments": "#7F848E"
 }
```

But it doesn't catch all types.

Is there an easier way to do this? Something like:

```
editor.fonts: {
    >use "dark+";
}
editor.background: {
    >use "one-dark-pro";
}
```

Comment: choose `One Dark Pro` as your theme and customize the `editor.background` color

Comment: I've tried this but there's way too many background parameters to configure, from the main editor background, to the terminal, sidebar, tabs and so on

Comment: find both theme definition files and copy paste the sections you want and create your own theme